# Ansible. How to run node.js application through pm2

Tags: node.js, ansible, pm2

What is the proper way to setup node.js app on Ubuntu server with Ansible?

Now I'm trying to register pm2 as a service like code below:

```
- name: install pm2
  npm:
    name: pm2
    global: yes
    state: present

- name: create pm2 init.d script
  template:
    src: pm2_init_config.j2
    dest: "/etc/init.d/pm2"
    backup: yes


- name: ensure pm2 service is started
  service:·
    name: pm2
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

but meet strange error:
`pm2 unrecognized service` in Ansible console

The pm2_init_config is similar to [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Unitech/pm2/master/lib/scripts/pm2-init.sh)

if I ssh to the box and run `sudo service pm2 start` everything works as expected

Comment: Can you post the `pm2_init_config.j2` file too?

Comment: Added but the problem isn't related to it

Comment: And what happens if you SSH into the box after running Ansible and try `service pm2 start`?

Comment: added details and an aswer

Comment: @kharandziuk I can't find the `pm2_init_config`, can you please share it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The change below fixed the problem:

```
 - name: create pm2 init.d script
   template:
        src: pm2_init_config.j2
        dest: "/etc/init.d/pm2"
        backup: yes
        mode: 0751
```

I don't know why it works. Can somebody explain this trick with mode?

Comment: Mode sets the file permissions, in this case you're setting the file to be executable (which is probably what's fixing it) by everybody, readable by the group. For more you should read up on chmod and chown.

Comment: I know about the modes in general. I guess you are right this happens because it makes the script executable. it is Very unintuitive detail I think